# Can we have a child flow that is calling from automate flow + from power apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I want to create a child flow inside a solution which get those details:-

1. Text of comma separated names
2. EndDate
3. StartDate
4. Type

The child floe will then create a separate SharePoint list item for each name as per the passed text of names and the related startdate, enddate & type

Now I want this process to be called from 2 locations:-

1. From Power Apps
2. From automate flow (when an item is added).

so is this possible? and how?